# Insert created forms inside application page

Tags: forms, bpmn, application-design, bonita, applicationpage

I'm making a transport request system with Bonita Soft. I've allready created 4 forms that I've assigned with 4 tasks in my Bonita process.

Now I want to create a Bonita application, so I have to complete the application descriptor file. I want to create my own custom pages for the application.

I would like to know if it was possible to insert the forms I've created previously inside my application page or not ?

The goal is that when the user click on the Bonita application, the first form (and then the three others) appears directly on the first page. Because now, the user has to go to the "process" tab and click on the start button, and it's not really practical.

(Bonita Soft version : 2022.2)

I made research about adding existing forms inside an application page but I didn't find anything. I also searched for an widget to use in the UI Designer but I didn't find what I want.

There's a widget called "Form container" but you cannot add an existing form in it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bonitasoft documentation](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/latest/pages-and-forms/forms):

> When it is submitted, a case (process instance) is created.
> At development time, an auto-generated form is provided by default, to ease process logic testing and debugging.
> It is based on the relevant contract.
> A custom form must be developed for user testing and production environments.

You'll have to create a page with form fields and a submit button, and have a JavaScript variable that builds the JSON object to then send to he Bonita engine to instantiate the process with.

Evoke has a good blog entry detailing how to do that [here](https://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/custom-page-integration-bonita-bpm/).